# How to put a Textbox on all word pages (No Header)?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I try to add a text box on each page to be able to modify in my own way (later) a book where it has "correct answers on that page (the pages will be on a specific page that I will not know until I develop it)".

This is my code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim oShp As Word.Shape
Dim i As Long

For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)

Dim Box As Shape
    Dim Sp() As String
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                             Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                             Left:=358.1, Top:=544, Width:=168, Height:=30)
    Sp = Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")
    


With Box
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = ("Respuestas correctas en la página")
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 9
            .Font.Color = wdColorWhite
            .Font.Italic = wdToggle
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
    End With


Next i
End Sub
```

The problem is that it repeats the cycle on the same page many times and does not go to the next page. How can I fix this without the headers?

Comment: See Word Does Not Know What a Page Is https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html. Word is a text reflow program, not a desktop publisher. You can use Frames, instead of Text Boxes. https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage These can be part of a Style which you could set, for instance, to be the style following a Heading 2 style which would start pages.

Comment: Ok, thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds it useful.
What is needed is a for loop and determining the variable `Rng` to put into `Anchor:=Rng`

```
Sub Text_box_all_pages()
Dim oShp As Word.Shape
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range, Shp As Shape
With ActiveDocument
  For i = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
  
    Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart

Set oShp = ActiveDocument.Shapes(i)

Dim Box As Shape
    Dim Sp() As String
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Name
    Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                             Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                             Left:=358.1, Top:=544, Width:=168, Height:=30, Anchor:=Rng)
    Sp = Split(ActiveDocument.Name, ".")
    


With Box
        With .TextFrame.TextRange
            .Text = ("Respuestas correctas en la página")
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 9
            .Font.Color = wdColorWhite
            .Font.Italic = wdToggle
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
    End With


Next i
End With
End Sub
```